# If a sequence converges to some L, then the limit of the nth partial sum divided by n is also L.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $x_n \to L$, prove that $\frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} \to L$.

So far I've got that because $x_n \to L$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-L|< \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq \mathbb{N}$.  From this it's not hard to show that $|x_{N}+\dots + x_m - (m-N)L| < \epsilon$, but I don't know how to deal with the beginning of the series $x_1 + \dots + x_{N-1}$, which I need to ultimately show

$
|\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{N-1}}{n} + \frac{x_N + \dots + x_n}{n} - L|<\epsilon
$
whenever $n \geq K$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the well-known Cesaro lemma: here is a proof:

http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~vittorio/CesaroMeans.pdf